# Why does the generated string contain a '\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, rsync

I have created this mre:

```
import subprocess

m = 'rsync'
url = 'mirror.nsc.liu.se/CentOS/7.8.2003/'
flags = '-avHP --delete '
destf = ''
url_prefix = 'rsync://'
root = '/tmp'
dest = 'test'

cmd = m + ' ' + flags + ' ' + url_prefix+url + ' ' +destf + ' ' + root+'/'+dest
print(cmd)
print(cmd.split(' '))
proc=subprocess.run(cmd.split(' '), capture_output=True)
print(proc.stderr)
```

Which gives me this output:

```
$ python3 test.py 
rsync -avHP --delete rsync://mirror.nsc.liu.se/CentOS/7.8.2003/  /tmp/test
['rsync', '-avHP', '--delete', '--bwlimit=800', 'rsync://mirror.nsc.liu.se/CentOS/7.8.2003/', '', '/tmp/test']
b'Unexpected local arg: \nIf arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1368) [Receiver=3.1.3]\n'
```

I really don't understand what's wrong here. There are no newlines in the string as far as I know.

If I change the creation of the command line to this (remove `destf`), the problem still remains:

```
cmd = '' + m + ' ' + flags + ' ' + url_prefix+url + ' ' + ' ' + root+'/'+dest
```

But with this (also remove one space) it works:

```
cmd = '' + m + ' ' + flags + ' ' + url_prefix+url + ' ' + root+'/'+dest
```

If I replace `' '` with `'  '` it stops working again. But when I enter the string directly in a shell, it works even with double spaces.

So what is actually happening here? I could use my findings above to shoehorn in a quick fix, but it feels like that will bite me later. So what is it I'm actually missing here? The reason I want the `destf` parameter is that it is set to `-P` when I'm using `wget` and could possibly be something else for another command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not complaining about a newline in the string. The error message has multiple lines, and the newline is the separator between the lines.

The unexpected argument is the empty string `''`  before `'/tmp/test'` because `destf` is empty.

When you use `.split(' ')`, multiple spaces are not merged into a single delimiter. So when you do

```
'foo  bar'.split(' ')
```

the result is

```
['foo', '', 'bar']
```

rather than

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

If you want multiple spaces to be coalesced into a single delimiter, use `.split()` instead of `.split(' ')`

```
proc=subprocess.run(cmd.split(), capture_output=True)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I have updated the question with information of why I have the parameter.

Comment: Use `.split()` instead of `.split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar for the answer that solved it. While I was out on lunch I realized what the problem was.

When a program is executed, it looks in a variable traditionally called `argv` which is basically an array of strings. The shell is usually responsible for converting a string into a string array, so if you invoke this command:

```
$ foo a   b c    eee
```

then, the shell will parse the string into:

```
argv[0] = "foo"
argv[1] = "a"
argv[2] = "b"
argv[3] = "c"
argv[4] = "eee"
```

But with the approach I used, it instead would end up in:

```
argv[0] = "foo"
argv[1] = "a"
argv[2] = ""
argv[3] = ""
argv[4] = "b"
argv[5] = "c"
argv[6] = ""
argv[7] = ""
argv[8] = ""
argv[9] = "eee"
```

So there was nothing wrong with the string. The problem was bypassing the conversion done by the shell. But using `.split()` instead of `.split(' ')` solved it.

Comment: Bear in mind that subprocess is not launching any shell, unless explicitly stated. The arguments are sent directly to rsync.